# How do I tell when my over medium eggs are done?

Tags: eggs, fried-eggs

I can make an egg over easy, but somehow I can't get over medium. I've tried different methods like lower heat, longer time and high heat, shorter time. At best I end up with a yolk that's overcooked on the edges, but still too runny in the center.

Comment: To save anyone else having to Google, in the American egg system 'over medium' means *the egg is flipped and the yolk is only slightly runny*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a lid? (or bowl, if on a flat-top griddle)

Trapping steam on top of the egg helps to cook it more evenly, IME (not that I claim to be all that good at it.) And it's not just me, as I've seen actual fry cooks use the bowl trick.

As for judging done-ness, that's a matter of "how jiggly is the yolk" but despite your title, your question seems to be more about how to achieve it, rather than how to judge it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a lid or bowl as mentioned is the best technique I've found IME. Using that trick in combination with medium heat provides a consistent result for me. While not *technically* part of the cooking process, keep residual heat in mind and make sure to transfer to a plate immediately.

Comment: in what way is this answer different than the already-present answer?